# How to rotate a UISwitch in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, view, storyboard, uiswitch

I have a UISwitch in my application. By default, it is horizontal. Am I able to rotate the switch so that it is vertical? I have no intentions of submitting this to the App Store, so  Apple's HIG are of no concern in my circumstance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, try changing the Transform attribute of the switches layer property. Should look something like this.

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(__ANGLE) ((__ANGLE) / 180.0 * M_PI)

UISwitch *aSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
aSwitch.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90), 0, 0, 1);
aSwitch.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, aSwitch.frame.size.width, aSwitch.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:aSwitch];
```

You can also edit with a CGAffineTransform, so you don't need to access the layer property.

So instead of

```
aSwitch.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90), 0, 0, 1);
```

you would have

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90));
```

Comment: How am I able to access the switches layer property? Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you've added the QuartzCore.framework to your project and imported it with #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your UISwitch is called "switchControl" and connected via Interface Builder, just write:

```
self.switchControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2); // 90 degrees
```

Using a function degrees to radians or vice versa:

```
/** Degrees to Radian **/
#define degreesToRadians( degrees ) ( ( degrees ) / 180.0 * M_PI )

/** Radians to Degrees **/
#define radiansToDegrees( radians ) ( ( radians ) * ( 180.0 / M_PI ) )

self.switchControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(90)); // 90 degrees
```